# Can I upload file to angular server?

Tags: node.js, angular, server, angular-cli

Does angular run on node server?

If yes then does `ng serve` run node server or angular server?

If it runs node server then can I upload file on this node server using angular?

My actual requirement is to edit a file (say en.json) in my project using angular. Can I do that just using the angular server because it runs on node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Angular isn't a 'server'. It's a framework. If you're talking about specific CLIs, running ng serve will start a Node server, it's all in their documentation, clear as day. Anyways, you shouldn't even try editing files using Angular, you can make http requests towards an endpoint via Angular and make your NodeJS server edit that specific file on your back-end. For uploading files check [this npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-upload) out, I've personally used it numerous times while I worked with Angular.